# Service architecture, continuously running vs. wake up

Tags: android

I have an application that wakes up at frequent intervals (once per minute) to do some stuff in the background.  I will be using the `AlarmManager` to schedule the wake ups.

I am looking at two different ways of structuring a `Service` to do the background work:

1. keep the service continuously running in the foreground with `setForeground()`.  This is attractive since the application state will remain in memory between wake-ups.
2. use `stopSelf()` to destroy the `Service` after it has finished running the background task.  This will require persisting some non-trivial objects between each wake up.

What are the pros and cons of each approach?  How costly is persistence?  What is the recommended approach for storage for case 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will be using the AlarmManager to schedule the wake ups.

Hopefully not if you are going with option #1. If your service will be running all of the time anyway, just use `Timer`.

> What are the pros and cons of each approach?

`setForeground()` doesn't work and hasn't for quite some time. `startForeground()` works, but it requires an active `Notification`.

A one-minute polling cycle is on the cusp of when I'd consider switching to `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`. That being said, a one-minute polling cycle is awfully frequent. I strongly encourage you to make this user-configurable, including an option for "please don't poll, I'll request updates through the UI".

> This will require persisting some non-trivial objects between each wake up.

You need to be persisting those objects in both cases. For example, when the user attacks your option #1 service with a task killer, it'd be nice if you did not lose their data.

> How costly is persistence?

It does not really matter, since you need to be be persisting those objects in both cases.

> What is the recommended approach for storage for case 2?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

You definently want to go with option 2 and stop your service once it's done. If you keep it running your going to keep using system resources, namely the battery. Do what you need to do, then stop the service. Also, what kind of wake up are you doing every minute? If you are doing a full-out device wake up (RTC_WAKEUP), you're once again going to kill the devices battery.

I hope this doesn't sound snooty, but I once heard a devloper say "Don't fight android, android will win". When you keep tyring to set your service to the foreground, you're fighting against androids attempts to clean up resources that aren't in use. You should instead embrace android. Do things as asynchronously as possible. That's the android way :)